# Detect new images added through ALAsset

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

Is there any way to check for new images through `ALAsset` library, like yesterday I fetched all images from the iPhone now I want to fetch or detect new images added today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API to perform custom fetches on the AssetsLibrary. I think the only solution to this problem is to enumerate the entire library, and check the metadata of each item to see if it is created after the last checked date. eg:

```
[assetsGroup enumerateUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDate *date = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
    if ([date laterDate:lastCheckedDate] == date) {
        // this is a new asset
    }
}];
```